# shoot кидать однокоренные?

Tags: этимология

Английский shoot и русское кидать родственник или это лажа?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы специально картинку вставили, чтобы затруднить жизнь желающему ответить?

Comment: А вообще - не по теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не готов поручиться за безошибочность каждого перехода, но вероятная родственность английского *shoot* и русского *кидать* не секрет. См. для примера [англо-викисловарь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shoot#Etymology_1) (я перевёл ключевые слова):

> Cognate with [**родственно с**] West Frisian sjitte, Low German scheten, Dutch schieten, German schießen, Danish skyde, Norwegian Bokmål skyte, Norwegian Nynorsk skyta, Swedish skjuta; and also, through [**а также через**] Indo-European, with Russian кида́ть (kidátʹ)